# How to convert console output to different format using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, binary, ascii, type-conversion

I want to convert file contents that I am reading using script to some toher format on console say plaintext or text from binary and other encrypted content stored in file.
Code example is following.I want to print contents in other format then original format stored in file:

```
File.open('somefile','rb') do |file|
  file.read.scan(/(.{4})(.{5})(.{3})(.{128})/).each do |a,b,c|
    puts "first 4 bytes: #{a}"
    puts "bytes 5 to 10: #{b}"
    puts "3 more bytes: #{c}"
  end
end
```

Please guide me how can I print file contents to desirable format or encoding.

Comment: You read data, transform to your "desirable format or encoding" and you print it. What's the question again?

Comment: Want to print original file content to converted data like binary to ASCII. File content is binary but I want to print it as ASCII on console